# How do I select distinct values from one column to insert into a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is what I'm trying but I get this error.

Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

I have these two tables:

table2:

| MY_NUM | DESCRIPTION | COL_2 | PHASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | APPLE | INFO | P1 |
| 124 | ORANGE | INFO | P1 |
| 124 | ORANGE | INFO_2 | P1 |
| 125 | BANANA | INFO | P2 |
| 125 | BANANA | INFO_2 | P2 |

table3:

| MY_NUM | COL_1 | PROJECT | COL_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | INFO | 1 | INFO |
| 123 | INFO_2 | 1 | INFO_2 |
| 124 | INFO | 2 | INFO |
| 124 | INFO_2 | 2 | INFO_2 |
| 125 | INFO | 1 | INFO |

The first thing I tried was

```
INSERT INTO table1 (MY_NUM, DESCRIPTION, PROJECT, PHASE)
SELECT t2.MY_NUM,
       t2.DESCRIPTION,
       t3.PROJECT,
       t2.PHASE,
  FROM table2 t2
 INNER JOIN table3 t3
       ON t2.MY_NUM = t3.MY_NUM;
```

and I got this error.

unique constraint (DASHBOARD.TABLE1_UK1) violated

MY_NUM is associated with multiple values in table2 and table3 so I tried to add unique values to the table for MY_NUM.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (MY_NUM, DESCRIPTION, PROJECT, PHASE)
SELECT (SELECT DISTINCT MY_NUM
          FROM table2),
       t2.DESCRIPTION,
       t3.PROJECT,
       t2.PHASE
  FROM table2 t2
 INNER JOIN table3 t3
       ON t2.MY_NUM = t3.MY_NUM;
```

And I got this error:

single-row subquery returns more than one row

I want something like this as the result:

| MY_NUM | DESCRIPTION | PROJECT | PHASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | APPLE | 1 | P1 |
| 124 | ORANGE | 2 | P1 |
| 125 | BANANA | 1 | P2 |

Where MY_NUM will not have duplicate values.
I've seen the partition by and group by clauses other people are using, but I'm not sure how to implement it into what I'm doing.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of what you want to do and tag with only one datbaser.

Comment: Presumably all your `INFO` values are actually different; so how do you want to choose which of those to copy into the new table for each `MY_NUM` value? Is there, for instance, a timestamp column in table2 and you want to get the most recent values?

Comment: Maybe I am being too ambiguous with my tables so I will make them a little more clear. Give me a second.

Comment: @AlexPoole my question is revised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your revised data, you just need to add the `distinct` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (MY_NUM, DESCRIPTION, PROJECT, PHASE)
SELECT distinct
       t2.MY_NUM,
       t2.DESCRIPTION,
       t3.PROJECT,
       t2.PHASE
  FROM table2 t2
 INNER JOIN table3 t3
       ON t2.MY_NUM = t3.MY_NUM;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5700a8166e7373c1868ab0cf642f84f4)

You seem to have denormalised data; for example the `phase` value appearing in two rows for the same `my_num`. If they are always matched then there should perhaps be a different table where that is only recorded once. As it is, they could end up with different values, which is either a data integrity issue;  or this query would need to decide which value to use, or it would be back to [a constraint violation](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3588586e53aaaea80024d18446ac64e5). You would then have to decide how to choose - based on some other column, or max/min, etc.

Comment: This is a case of me overcomplicating things for myself. I think, for example, phase might be updated but the old phase remains, so I think your min/ max answer is best suited for this query

Comment: I didn't even need to use min/max I just needed distinct. I can't believe I did that to myself lol.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a subquery for `MY_NUM` when you have it as a result of the `JOIN`?  Doesn't this do what you want?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (MY_NUM, COL_1, COL_2, COL_3)
    SELECT t2.MY_NUM, t2.COL_1, t3.COL_2, t2.COL_3
    FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN
         table3 t3
         ON t2.MY_NUM = t3.MY_NUM;
```

Comment: MY_NUM has duplicate values in both of the other tables and I want the individual values.

Comment: @TheSchmidly . . . You need to explain this clearly in the **question**.  Not in a comment.

Comment: I've revised my question. does that help?

Comment: @TheSchmidly . . . No.  It does not show the data you are starting with.

Comment: I've revised it again. Is this better?

Comment: btw you're answer is actually the first thing I tried to do so I included it in my question.